# How do I change device location?

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I change device location with expo or react-native?
Fake location coordinate!

Example : 
location:  { coords: { latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324 }}
... change device location.

Comment: Grammar and spelling

Answer (score 2):

To change the device's location, you can either use built-in emulator function or fake GPS application on your physical device.

For the emulator, you can do it easily, just click triple dots (...) on the right menu, then go to Location context.

[image]

Comment: no. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsmartstudio.fakegps&hl=tr this app

Answer (score 0):

For the Android real device, you can use Lockito or Fake GPS Location.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=tr
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsmartstudio.fakegps&hl=tr

for iOS, you can use iMyFone AnyTo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).